# Squeak smalltalk mouse listener or keyboard listener

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

Hello i am busting my head open to find out how to use mouse listener in 
squeak Small talk  or keyboard listener

Please help me and tell me how is it done ?

Comment: What is "mouse listener"? Is it a class? What do you want to achieve? E.g. Do you need the mouse position? Do you need events?

Comment: 1.  how do i get CLICK from a mouse (left / right click)
2.  how do i get mouse  cordinates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [MorphicDraw documentation](https://github.com/StephanEggermont/MorphicDraw).
It has some examples of reacting to mouse events and moving shapes around on the screen. 
You can find the code at

```
MCHttpRepository
location: 'http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/StephanEggermont/MorphicDraw/main'
user: ''
password: ''
```

At the moment it only loads in Pharo (some missing dependencies for Squeak), but the mouse event handling should be the same.